# how to remove first character in each line of textarea

Tags: javascript, html

The output should be displayed as `LUNG`,`KIDNEY`,`SKELETON>J169>U` and `E`, `CREATININE:no` instead of `>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E`, `CREATININE:no`
How to achieve this using javascript? i,e ">" is the first character in each line needs to be removed.

I have used string replace and string charAt functions to remove the first charahter in each line, but did'nt workout for me. 
Please correct me if i am going wrong somewhere in the coding?
Below snippet helps to understand the issue more appropriately!

Advance Thanks

```
function change(){
   var lines = $('#te1').val().split("\n");
                      for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++)
                      {
                      var res1=lines[i].replace(lines[i].charAt(0),"");
                         $("#te1").val(res1)
                      }  
   }


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="te1" cols="100" rows="5">
>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no
>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes
</textarea>

<button id = "b1" onclick="change()">Remove</button>
```

Comment: `for(...) {str += lines[i].substring(1) } $(...).val(str);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) :

```
$('#te1').val($('#te1').val().split("\n").map(str => str.length && str.charAt(0) == '>' ? str.substr(1) : str).join('\n'));
```

Here is the explanation :

```
$('#te1').val(          //Assign to your textarea what's coming next
    $('#te1').val()     //Get what's inside your textarea
    .split("\n")        //Split it to every newline
    .map(str =>         //Go through your array
        str.length && str.charAt(0) == '>' ?    //If the String isn't empty and it has a > at its beginning
        str.substr(1)   //Removes the first char
        : str           // Else keep the String as is
    )
    .join('\n')         //Rejoin your array with newlines
);
```

**Demo :**

```js
function change() {
  $('#te1').val($('#te1').val().split("\n").map(str => str.length && str.charAt(0) == '>' ? str.substr(1) : str).join('\n'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="te1" cols="100" rows="5">
>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no

>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes
</textarea>

<button id="b1" onclick="change()">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Its working but it is also removing other alphabets on clicking remove button which shouldn't be happenning. In my case it should remove only " > " at first place but not other characters. The other characters should remain the same on clicking remove button. Could you please help me Zenoo?  thanks in advance!

Comment: @SwaroopGanesh I added a condition.

Comment: On first click,  LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no
LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes      on second,  UNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no

UNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes  i.e, L is been removed               on third, NG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no
NG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes i.e., L and U has been removed. Likewise it keeps on removing each letters which shouldn't  happened.  It should only remove ">" NOTHING ELSE irrespective of clicks.

Comment: @SwaroopGanesh That's already what it does with the added condition. Refresh your page and try it out.

Comment: Thank you Sir. My bad I actually didn't refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`, `substring` and `join`

```
function change() {
  var lines = $('#te1').val().split("\n");
  $("#te1").val(lines.map ( s => s.substring(1) ).join("\n"));
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function change() {
  var lines = $('#te1').val().split("\n");
  console.log(lines);
  $("#te1").val(lines.map ( s => s.substring(1) ).join("\n"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="te1" cols="100" rows="5">
>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no

>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes
</textarea>

<button id="b1" onclick="change()">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.prototype.substr` you can remove the first char at each line, and then combine it back.

```js
function change() {
  const $tel = $("#te1");
  const lines = $tel.val().split("\n");
  $tel.val(lines.map((line) => line.substr(1)).join('\n'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="te1" cols="100" rows="5">
>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no

>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes
</textarea>

<button id="b1" onclick="change()">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the answers are based on loops, following is an approach that uses regex:

#### Idea:

- Create a regex that captures the line into 2 groups:

  - Group1: First character
  - Group2: Rest of the string.
- Now replace string with `Group2`.

```js
function change() {
  var lines = $('#te1').val();
  var regex = /([^\n])([^\n]+\n?)/g;
  $('#te1').val(lines.replace(regex, "$2"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="te1" cols="100" rows="5">
>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no

>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes
</textarea>

<button id="b1" onclick="change()">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [multiline flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline) to make `^` match the start of a line in a RegExp.

```js
function change(){
   $('#te1').val((index, value) => value.replace(/^[^\n]/gm, ""));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="te1" cols="100" rows="5">
>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>J169>U and E, CREATININE:no

>LUNG,KIDNEY,SKELETON>G121:yes
</textarea>

<button id = "b1" onclick="change()">Remove</button>
```